# How to invoke Single argument constructor in this program involving class template?

Tags: c++, constructor, class-template

This is the code I wrote to get started with class templates.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
template<class T>
class Complex
{
T *real,*imag;
public:
    Complex(T a)
    {
    real=new T;
    imag=new T;
        *real=a;
        *imag=0;
    }
    Complex(T a,T b)
    {
    real=new T;
    imag=new T;
        *real=a;
        *imag=b;
    }
    Complex()
    {
    real=new T;
    imag=new T;
        *real=0;
        *imag=0;
    }   
template<class R>       
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &out,Complex<R> &C);
template<class R>
friend istream& operator>>(istream &in,Complex<R> &C);
template<class R>
friend Complex<R> operator +(Complex<R> a,Complex<R> b);    
};
template<class R>
ostream& operator<<(ostream &out,Complex<R> &C)
    {
    out<<"The number is "<<*C.real<<"+"<<*C.imag<<"i"<<endl;
    return out; 
    }
template<class R>       
istream& operator>>(istream &in,Complex<R> &C)
    {
    cout<<"Enter the number ";
    in>>*C.real>>*C.imag;
    return in;  
    }
template<class R>       
Complex<R> operator +(Complex<R> a,Complex<R> b)
{
Complex<R> temp;
*temp.real=*a.real+*b.real;
*temp.imag=*a.imag+*b.imag;
return temp;    
}       
int main()
{
Complex<float> C1,C2(4.2,6.8),C3,C4;
C1=5;
C3=3+C1;
C4=C2+C3;
cout<<C1;
cout<<C2;
cout<<C3;
cout<<C4;
}
```

This code everything works fine except when I try to use an integer value like '3+C2' it shows error. If the same code is considered without using templates for '3+C2' invokes the friend function operator+(Complex a,Complex b) and 3 being copied to object a which invokes single argument constructor and 3 will be assigned to the real part of the Complex class. How to make the same happen when class templates are used? How to invoke the single argument constructor when a number is passed to operator+() function instead of Complex object when class templates are used?

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ The error arises in the + operator function.Passing integer values resulting in error as single argument constructor is not invoked. I need to know how to use C2=3+C1 while using class template. thank you

Comment: Your code is badly flawed from the bone. Stop using raw pointers and `new` for starters.

Comment: You should delete most of this code and start again from `T real,imag;` . It will save a lot of time in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

With something like

```
template<class R>
Complex<R> operator +(Complex<R>, Complex<R>);
```

The type `R` is deduced independently from each function argument; both deduction must succeed and the deduced type must match for this to be usable. Since 3 is not a `Complex`, deduction fails and the overload is not considered.

There are two ways to solve this. One is to use a non-template friend:

```
template<class T>
class Complex {
   // ...
   friend Complex operator+(Complex a, Complex b) {
      // ...
   }
};
```

This instantiates into a non-template friend function, which is happy to consider implicit conversions.

The other approach is to supply additional overloads that deduce only from one argument:

```
template<class T> struct identity { using type = T; };
template<class T> using nondeduced_t = typename identity<T>::type;

template<class R>
Complex<R> operator +(nondeduced_t<Complex<R>>, Complex<R>) { /* ... */ }

template<class R>
Complex<R> operator +(Complex<R>, nondeduced_t<Complex<R>>) { /* ... */ }
```

This is the approach taken by `std::basic_string_view`.

---

By the way, the implementation you have is badly broken. It leaks memory like there's no tomorrow - and there's no reason to dynamically allocate the `T`s in the first place.

Comment: So we will finally have string_view standartized? I didn't know!

Comment: @SergeyA It's part of fundamentals V1 that has been merged into C++17.